# Fetch data between time difference

Tags: oracle

I want to fetch transactions happened between 10 mins . I have table with column transfer date, transfer Id but i only want to fetch those transfer id that had been generated within 10 mins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will give you those transfer_id which have occurred in the past 10 minutes, given that this can be determined by transfer_date.

```
select transfer_id
  from transactions
 where transfer_date > sysdate - interval '10' minute
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this :

```
select transfer_id, transfer_date from my_table where transfer_id in
(
  select transfer_id from my_table
  minus
  select transfer_id from my_table as of timestamp systimestamp - interval '10' minute
)
```

i have to emphasize that your db's flashback mode should be on (if not, your dba should issue the following command):

> alter database flashback on

Comment: Thanx , Its working, Kindly suggest how to get those transactions among which time difference is 10 mins like If I have 10 transactions but I want to fetch only those transactions between which time difference is 10 mins

Comment: @ok, you're welcome but i couldn't understand your last question.

Comment: Ok, Let me explain, suppose I have table with two columns  TRANSFER_ID, TRANSFER_DATE . Now in 1st column I have 10 records and in 2nd column date-time (time of transfer_id when it got generated) now I only want to fetch those transfer_id among which time difference is 10 mins

Comment: @user8864478 what i've written in my answer is enough for your need exactly, also  the answer of Ronnis satisfies what you want. Both are true, there may be different ways, but all can arrive to Rome or Baghdad etc. :)